# How can I test that a "dereferenced" lambda is passed to a method?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Consider this code:

```
def thing_incrementer
  lambda do
    self.foo +=1
    save!
  end
end

def increment_thing
  with_lock &thing_incrementer
end
```

How can I write a test which tests that the `thing_incrementer` is passed with `with_lock` as a block? If I just wanted to test that it was passed as a parameter (without the leading `&`) I would do this:

```
let(:the_lambda){ lambda{} }
x.stub(:thing_incrementer){ the_lambda }
x.should_receive(:with_lock).with(the_lambda)
x.increment_thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `&thing_incrementer` passes a proc which gets bound as a block to `with_thing`. So, just test for that:

```
expect(subject).to receive(:with_lock).with(no_args) do |&blk|
  expect(blk).to be_a(Proc)
end
```

If you want to pass a lambda as an argument, then you wouldn't prefix it with `&` and it would just get passed as a normal argument, but then you'd have to call `blk.call` (or whatever) rather than just yielding to the block.

To check that you're receiving the lambda you want:

```
class Foo
  def incrementor
    -> {}
  end

  def increment
    with_lock &incrementor
  end

  def with_lock
    yield
  end
end

describe "Lock" do
  subject { Foo.new }
  let(:the_lambda) { -> {} }
  before do
    expect(subject).to receive(:incrementor).and_return(the_lambda)
  end

  it "should receive the_lambda from the incrementor" do
    expect(subject).to receive(:with_lock).with(no_args) do |&blk|
      expect(blk).to eq(the_lambda)
    end
    subject.increment
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! a few questions. 1) "If you want to pass a lambda as an argument" - why do you mention this? did it seem like that might be the case from my question? (it's not) 2) how would i test that `the_lambda` is what gets passed in proc form to `with-lock`? (i don't think your example covers this, or I'm missing it...)

Comment: 1) I just mentioned it because sometimes you want to pass a proc (or multiple procs) as args, and the difference is just passing them directly vs binding them as blocks. 2) You would just test that `blk == lambda` in the expect block, but you would probably have to use an actual lambda rather than a double, since it would need to be bindable.

Comment: I just changed my example to use an actual lambda -- wanna modify your answer to check that this is the one passed?

Comment: Done. Does that help clarify it?

Comment: awesome. i guess to nipick further: IMO no need to redefine the example methods, just use the ones that I have in my question.

Comment: Heh, sorry, I ended up actually running those tests and just threw together that example class to test with.